# Using the groupby function in pandas, how can I create new dataframe columns that hold sums for each groupby "level"

Tags: python, pandas

| Customer | Service Type | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo. | A. | 25. |
| foo. | B. | 50. |
| foo. | C | 15. |
| bar | A | 25. |
| bar. | b | 10. |

How can I get the table above to look like the one below:

| Customer | Service Type A Revenue | Service Type B Revenue | Service Type C Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo. | 25 | 50. | 15 |
| bar | 25 | 10 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked on my side:

```
data_stack = {'Customer': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar'], 'Service Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
'Revenue': [25,50,15,25,10]}
stack_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_stack)
```

Then group the info per columns:

```
grouped_info = stack_df.groupby(['Customer', 'Service Type']).sum()
```

Unstack or unpivot the Service Types column:

```
final_df = grouped_info.unstack(level=-1)
```

Drop any unneeded columns or multiindex items:

```
final_df.columns = final_df.columns.droplevel()
```

Rename columns how you want them:

```
final_df.set_axis(['Service Type A Revenue', 'Service Type B Revenue', 'Service Type A Revenue'], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
#df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.str.strip('.'))

out = df.pivot(*df.columns).add_prefix('Service Type ')
```